# php defined constant in if/else shorthand

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a php course, and one of the exercises has us create a config.php file wherein we define database constants.

I know the standard way of doing this, which is:

```
define("NAME", "value");
```

However, this exercise has it written differently. It's in if/else shorthand. 
Now I know it's correct, because it works. 
But I don't understand *WHY* it works. 
Hopefully it's a simple answer for you more experienced devs:

```
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
```

The way I read it, it's checking to see if DB_SERVER is defined. 
If it's true, then it sets it to NULL ?

Why would it NULL out the value of that constant if it's already defined?

Comment: Try writing that out as an `if/else` statement.

Comment: This is not really the intended way to use the ternary operator. Unless you feel you are a rockstar or something. Use `if` instead in situations like this for better readability.

Comment: That really isn't a very good use of a ternary. If we're trying to be rockstars, we should write it like `defined('DB_SERVER') || define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');` ;)

Comment: @DaggNabbit Or as `defined('DB_SERVER') or define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');`, in case you need to use `&&` in your condition.

Comment: @RobertK mixing `&&` or `||` with the text versions `and` and `or` is a good way to write hard to read code. You're better of using brackets `()`.

Comment: @Arjan As soon as you start mixing text/symbol operators in a line like the above, you should be using an `if` statement anyway. Just saying that you could actually do it without.

Answer (score 4):

If it's defined, it runs the expression `null`, which is essentially a noop (does nothing).  Otherwise, it actually runs `define`.  You could write this as `defined('DB_SERVER') ?: define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost')` nowadays, but I personally think that it is confusing.  I would have simply written it as:

```
if (!defined('DB_SERVER')) {
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
}
```

Comment: Wow, can I just say how awesome this is. My first post ever, and it was answered and understood in less than 10 minutes.
I think I'm going to like stackoverflow :)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the long-hand form:

```
if ( defined('DB_SERVER') )
{
    // Do nothing
}
else
{
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
}
```

In English:

> If someone already defined 'DB_SERVER', leave it alone
>
> Otherwise, define it with the value of 'localhost'

Comment: I think you're missing a few parentheses...

Comment: @Vector: Few (adj.): a small number of. ;)

Comment: An even smaller number, now.

Comment: my bad, I always associated "few" as 3+